# Convert Map<?, Map<?, ?> to List of Objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following collection:

```
Map<String, Map<SomeEnum, Long>> map = ...
```

Here's sample data:

```
{"Foo": {
    SomeEnum.BAR1: 1,
    SomeEnum.BAR2: 2,
    SomeEnum.BAR3: 3
  },
 "two": {...}
```

Since I know all enums, I want to convert it to the list of POJO. The definition of the object is as below:

```
class SomeClass {
  String name;
  long bar1Value;
  long bar2Value;
  long bar3Value;
}
```

I have tried different solutions, like with mapping inside mapping:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
.map(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(innerEntry -> {
  long bar1 = 0;
  long bar2 = 0;
  long bar3 = 0;

  if(innerEntry.getKey().equals(SomeEnum.BAR1)) bar1 = innerEntry.getValue();
  if(innerEntry.getKey().equals(SomeEnum.BAR2)) bar2 = innerEntry.getValue();
  if(innerEntry.getKey().equals(SomeEnum.BAR3)) bar3 = innerEntry.getValue();

  return new SomeClass(e.getKey(), bar1, bar2, bar3);
}).collect(toList()).collect(toList());
```

Unfortuantely, what I am getting is `List<List<SomeClass>>`.

Is there any other, more elegant, way to handle this?

Comment: You are comparing `String` to `Enum`. This will not work. You may want to try comparing using the string representation of the enum

Comment: It's correct, the key in the inner map is an enum.

Comment: Maybe you require `flatMap()` method?

Comment: You're right. I missed that. You should try `flatMap` instead of `map` as suggested

Comment: Your map says your inner map is an Enum,Long but your example shows String, Long.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @WJS my bad, the sample data is in JSON format. The correct version is the signature.

Comment: I'm not familiar with manipulating JSON but I've seen enough posts about it that using Jackson to parse JSON and create maps and other things is an option.  Just in case you  were not aware.

Comment: @WJS fixed that in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work for you?

It requires a constructor for the target class but simply gets the values and creates an instance. Then it collects them to a list.

```
        List<SomeClass> list = map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new SomeClass(e.getKey(),
                        e.getValue().get(SomeEnum.BAR1),
                        e.getValue().get(SomeEnum.BAR2),
                        e.getValue().get(SomeEnum.BAR3)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Class with constructor

```
class SomeClass {
    String name;
    long bar1Value;
    long bar2Value;
    long bar3Value;

    public SomeClass(String name, long bar1Value, long bar2Value,
        long bar3Value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bar1Value = bar1Value;
        this.bar2Value = bar2Value;
        this.bar3Value = bar3Value;
    }       
}
```

Comment: `e.getValue().getOrDefault(SomeEnum.BAR1,0L)` to be [compiling at least](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511407/1746118) :)

Comment: I decided against that while I was editing since the OP never suggest that the any of the Enum values were missing.  Also, it wouldn't be right once I saw that you had done it so I took mine out.

Comment: And this  whole thing confuses me since the OP's example shows a String in his inner Map as a key.

Comment: 1. choosing not to set a default value as in OP's code is prone to NullPointerException. 2. The representation of enum in JSON is its name, so there is not much wrong with it apart from the fact, that the name *mostly* resolves to an enum value itself.

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify the complete task with a utility to create `SomeClass` from the inner map:

```
private SomeClass createSomeClass(String name, Map<SomeEnum, Long> innerMap) {
    return SomeClass.builder()
            .name(name)
            .bar1Value(innerMap.getOrDefault(SomeEnum.BAR1, 0L))
            .bar2Value(innerMap.getOrDefault(SomeEnum.BAR2, 0L))
            .bar3Value(innerMap.getOrDefault(SomeEnum.BAR3, 0L))
            .build();
}
```

and then your mapping would be as easy as --

```
List<SomeClass> someClassList = map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> createSomeClass(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `map` to `flatMap` and remove 1st `toList()`

```
List<SomeClass> ss = map.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(innerEntry -> {
                    long bar1 = 0;
                    long bar2 = 0;
                    long bar3 = 0;

                    if(innerEntry.getKey().equals(SomeEnum.BAR1)) bar1 = innerEntry.getValue();
                    if(innerEntry.getKey().equals(SomeEnum.BAR2)) bar2 = innerEntry.getValue();
                    if(innerEntry.getKey().equals(SomeEnum.BAR3)) bar3 = innerEntry.getValue();

                    return new SomeClass(e.getKey(), bar1, bar2, bar3);
                })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, it flattens the map, however, there is still an issue - the new list contains a new object for each positive if. From my sample code, object with name "Foo" will be created three times, since three values are there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

Firstly add a method to set de specific long for each enum value, something like this:

```
class SomeClass {

    String name;
    long bar1Value;
    long bar2Value;
    long bar3Value;
```

> //GETTERS AND SETTERS

```
    public void setByEnum(SomeEnum t, Long value) {
        switch (t) {
            case BAR1:
                this.setBar1Value(value);
                break;
            case BAR2:
                this.setBar2Value(value);
                break;
            case BAR3:
                this.setBar3Value(value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to make loop the map, something like this:

```
 List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    map.forEach((name,values)->{
        SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
        s.setName(name);
        values.forEach((t,value)->{
            s.setByEnum(t, value);
        });
        list.add(s);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
for(int i=0; i<keyList.size(); i++){
    Map innermap = map.get(keyList.get(i));
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass(keyList.get(i),innermap.get('bar1'),innermap.get('bar2'),innermap.get('bar3');
}
```